# Call a function in viewController from an extension?

Tags: swift

I’m using this extension to customise my keyboard with extra options.

```
    extension UITextField {

func addNumericAccessory(addPlusMinus: Bool) {
    let numberToolbar = UIToolbar()
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default

    var accessories : [UIBarButtonItem] = []

    if addPlusMinus {
        accessories.append(UIBarButtonItem(title: "+/-", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(plusMinusPressed)))
        accessories.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil))   //add padding after
    }

    accessories.append(UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(numberPadClear)))
    accessories.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil))   //add padding space
    accessories.append(UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(numberPadDone)))

    numberToolbar.items = accessories
    numberToolbar.sizeToFit()

    inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar
}

@objc func numberPadDone() {
    self.resignFirstResponder()
}

@objc func numberPadClear() {
    self.text = ""
}

@objc func plusMinusPressed() {
    guard let currentText = self.text else {
        return
    }
    if currentText.hasPrefix("-") {
        let offsetIndex = currentText.index(currentText.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let substring = currentText[offsetIndex...]  //remove first character
        self.text = String(substring)
    }
    else {
        self.text = "-" + currentText
    }
}

}
```

How can I get the numberPadDone function to call a function in my viewController?

I need to update other TextFields and I can’t access them in extension. Is there a way to call out updateTextFields() that’s in my viewController?

Edit:

This function is in my viewController
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0kpS.png

Calling the function from extension
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aywzP.png

Moving @objc func numberPadDone() to viewController
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5di8d.png

To summarise, I need this extension to add minus to my keyboard, but also need to call functions in my viewController. The problem I’m getting is I can’t access my viewController apart from the TextField this extension is for via self.

Comment: so what issue you are facing ? any error on accessing them in controller ?

Comment: they should be accessible

Comment: self.text is accessible but my custom functions in my script come out as unidentified. What you can’t see in the example is self.updateTextFields() which is a function in my viewController. And I get an error that updateTextField() is unidentified.

Comment: can show show your viewController ? and error screen shot ?

Comment: Updated my question with screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are accessible, but at first time autocompletion may not work properly. Just call `self.numberPadDone` from UITextField, or `text.numberPadDone`, where `text: UITextField` from viewController

Comment: Should I move the func numberPadDone to my view controller? Because currently it’s within the extension. And I want to call my own function from it.

Comment: It depends from Your task. If each UITextField must contain some additional functionality - better to extend UITextField. If You need to calculate something in one point - better to move it in higher part of code (UIViewContoler, Model, ViewModel or any other, depends from choose architecture)